Can i use PrimeVue components with tailwind prefix "tw-"?
I am currently trying to refactor Nuxt 3 project from Bootstrap to Tailwind with PrimeVue components. Because of that, I am using the Railwind prefix tw- for Tailwind classes to separate them from Bootstrap classes. The problem is that when I use prefixes, PrimeVue components break down. Is there a way to fix this issue with some configuration? Am I missing something? Thank you for your help.
I tried to rewrite the ./presets/lara/dropdown component with the prefix, but it is not helping.
